# Inverse of geometry_msgs/pose

Tags: geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's the best way to find the inverse of a geometry_msgs/Pose message?

Or in general to perform any other matrix manipulations. Does ROS provide a library or functions to do so? And if not, which is the default method used by the ROS community?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205223/inverse-of-geometry_msgs/pose/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2015-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If with "inverse of pose" you mean something that deals with transforms and their inverses, then you're probably looking for the [tf](http://wiki.ros.org/tf) system in ROS.

If you're just starting with this, [tf2](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2) might actually be better, as it is the successor to `tf`.

See the various tutorials for more info on how to use both.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2015-03-17**:
The "pose" in my case represents a child coordinate frame (frame B) in parent coordinates (frame A). I want to find out the inverse of that (A in coordinates of B).

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2022-06-30**:
Pose and Transform are equivalent. And it makes sense to avoid tf when needing the inverse of a pose sometimes.